# CodeMirror React implement find and replace

Tags: reactjs, codemirror, react-codemirror

I am trying to implement my own search interface for a Codemirror instance. I am currently using [react-codemirror2](https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2) and my Component has a CodeMirror instance like:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    state = {find:''}

    constructor() {
      this.codeMirror = null;
    }

    onFind = () => {
        let cursor = this.codeMirror.getSearchCursor(this.state.find, false);
    }

    render() {
      <CodeMirror editorDidMount={editor => { this.codeMirror = editor }}/>

      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.find} onChange={(e) => {this.setState({find: e.target.value})}} />
        <a onClick={this.onFind}>Find</a>
      </div>

    }
}
```

I am trying to use the addons provided with CodeMirror at the beginning of the file like:

```
import 'codemirror/addon/search/search.js';
import 'codemirror/addon/search/searchcursor.js';
```

`getSearchCursor` returns a `SearchCursor` Object inside my `OnFind` method but how do I use it to highlight matches ? To replace the occurrence with another string ? It seems very difficult to use the addons functions.

The addons section is documented here: [Addons](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addons)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the cursor.findnext and [markText](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#markText) function of code mirror you can add a class to hightlight. "markerClassName" is a custom class we need to pass.

```
onFind = () => {
    const cursor = this.codeMirror.getSearchCursor(this.state.find, false);
    while (cursor.findNext()) {
        this.codeMirror.markText(cursor.from(), cursor.to(), {
            className: markerClassName
        });
    }
}
```

See the example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/crystalthinker/at7owes8/). 
Can refer the searchcursor code implementation for reference [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/38213275/).